# Use Gregorian Date with non English Culture in Abp framework .NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

When changing the language in ASP.net boilerplate (.NET core 3 with Angular) the date in the UI has been changed to Ar Culture I wanna use Gregorian Date with Ar Culture.
Is there any straight forward solution without lots of workarounds I found below suggestions solution but I don't prefer such that solutions

https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=26993

Edited (more details):

in Abp framework there is a multi-language option, So when I switch the language to Arabic the whole system culture switched to Arabic culture with Hijri date format, I want to change the system to Arabic culture with gregorian date, How Could I do that and if there is a customized code where should I put it  (for example in Startup.cs class) because I've tried customized code but the system didn't accept it in Configure Function in Startup.cs class

Startup.cs class code

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
/*****************************************************************************/

            CultureInfo myCIintl = new CultureInfo("ar-SA", false);
            Calendar[] myOptCals = new CultureInfo("ar-SA").OptionalCalendars;
            // Checks which ones are GregorianCalendar then determines the GregorianCalendar version.
            Console.WriteLine("The ar-SA culture supports the following calendars:");
            foreach (Calendar cal in myOptCals)
            {

                if (cal.GetType() == typeof(GregorianCalendar))
                {

                    GregorianCalendar myGreCal = (GregorianCalendar)cal;
                    myCIintl.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = myGreCal;
                    GregorianCalendarTypes calType = myGreCal.CalendarType;
                    Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1})", cal, calType);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", cal);
                }
            }
/*****************************************************************************/

            app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

            app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("defaultWithArea", "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
            app.UseSwagger();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint(_appConfiguration["App:ServerRootAddress"].EnsureEndsWith('/') + "swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApp API V1");
                options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp .Web.Host.wwwroot.swagger.ui.index.html");
            }); // URL: /swagger
        }
```

Comment: Boilerplate is just a third-party framework. It doesn't change how ASP.NET Core itself works with dates. What are you actually trying to do? I suspect there are a *lot* of duplicate questions that say "you can't do that". PS: The certificate on that page is expired. Explain what you want in the question itself

Comment: PPS: Given that Boilerplate is an ASP.NET framework and that link is clearly a PHP page, that returns a certificate expiration error, don't expect people to touch that link with anything short of hazmat suits

Comment: Have you checked [How to: Display Dates in Non-Gregorian Calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-dates-in-non-gregorian-calendars)? Dates have no culture, they have calendars. The DateTime is treated internally as a Gregorian date, no matter the Calendar. Perhaps all you need to do is change the *format string* used to display dates? Or use a custom culture that uses a different Date format string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos than you, I've added more details could you, please check it?

Comment: Any new information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution (easy workaround solution):

first of all, if you want a rich of information related to date and calendar review [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/working-with-calendars) but what I did is:

1- Go to **AbpLanguages** database table and delete all records.

2- In **DefaultLanguagesCreator** class change the *ar* to *ar-EG* because the default calendar for *ar* Culture is System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar but *ar-EG* culture the default calendar for it is System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar (the calendar that I want)

3- then clean, rebuild the solution.

4- Don't forget to change the culture inside the XML localization file to *ar-EG*.